# angularJS display base64 image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app i try to display base64 image...

for example i have:

```
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
```

on url: `{{user.Photo}}`

and in ng-repeat loop i have:

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{user.Photo}}" data-err-src="images/png/avatar.png"/>
```

but as result i see:

```
data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,http://location.com/files/idididididid"
```

but why? how to display my image data?

Comment: Is the `user.Photo` variable correct?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the value of `ng-src`?

Comment: ng-src - content of url

Comment: @Nano yes is correct

Comment: @DavinTryon there is url with base64 data

Comment: @DavinTryon https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/blob here is example

Comment: @brabertaser1992 why you delete your question? ok , use this `string.split(/([^\/]+\/)|;[^,]+,/g)`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If the image is from remote server, you can fetch the base64 content in your controller like this:

```
$http.get($scope.user.photo).then(function(response) {
    $scope.user.data = response.data;
});
```

then display it on view

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{user.data}}" data-err-src="images/png/avatar.png"/>
```

While if the image is on local disk/phone, first you can get the image data from `FileReader`

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");

// files is a FileList object (similar to NodeList)
var files = fileInput.files;
$scope.imageSrc = files[0].getAsDataURL();
```

then bind the `$scope.imageSrc` to view as `<img ng-src="imageSrc" >`

Comment: but how to be with images on mobile phones etc? it's better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137431/angularjs-make-binary-data-image-from-base64-and-send-as-image-file-to-server

Comment: @brabertaser1992 you mean displaying local images on mobile phones?

Comment: Per two questions you posted, you want to crop local image and send the cropped one to the server, right?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I have updated my answer. The workflow is likely to be    : choose local image/show it on view/crop the image/get the image binary data from base64/send the image binary to server.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I just merged this question with another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137431/angularjs-make-binary-data-image-from-base64-and-send-as-image-file-to-server/28247398?noredirect=1#comment44856100_28247398) you posted. I suppose my answer simply solved the binding issue here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69939/discussion-between-rebornix-and-brabertaser1992).

Comment: Just a heads up for future people who read this, the string that came back from my sql database already had the "data:image/png;base64," part in it so in that case i just made it  `data-ng-src="{{user.data}}"`

Answer (score 17):

Call image data with a function like this:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{getImage(doc.image)}}" />
```

in controller:

```
$scope.getImage = function(data){
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply do something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{myObject.userImage}}">
```

For jpeg:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{myObject.userImage}}">
```

This is for AngularJS 1.x.x

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2, this is done as follows

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{myObj.base64EncodedImage}}" />
```