# Display image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I pick an image, at times it does not display, but when I click a second time, the image is displayed.

**jQuery**

```
$('#morefiles').change(function (event) {
  if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test($(this).val())) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Message',
      template: 'You must select an image file only !'
    });
    $('#morefiles').val('');
  } else {
    var obj = {};
    obj.key = event.target.files[0];
    obj.value = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    $scope.items.push(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    $('#morefiles').val(obj);
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" multiple="" id="morefiles" accept="image/*" >
```

How to solve this problem? When the user selects an image I need to display the image at that time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this will help you more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235246/angularjs-display-base64-image

Comment: Where are you clicking to display the image?

Comment: thanks for replay @Prajwal K M but i not use to store image in remote server i only use to display image

Comment: display at second time click (e.g. when i select image than preview screen now i click in page or any form control than it will be display ) @sideroxylon

Comment: $scope.items.push(obj);  You need to set ng-src with scope items. For which perpose you write $('#morefiles').val(obj);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I got you.. Add this line:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

to your code as below:

```
$('#morefiles').change(function (event) {
                if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test($(this).val())) {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Message',
                        template: 'You must select an image file only !'
                    });
                    $('#morefiles').val('');
                } else {
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.key = event.target.files[0];
                    obj.value = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                    $scope.items.push(obj);
                    $scope.$apply()
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

                    $('#morefiles').val(obj);
                }
            });
```

I too faced this problem. But solved this way. I dont know why I need to do `$scope.$apply();`. I dont have enough time to dig the stuff. If anyone knows the reason for it, you are most welcome to comment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#morefiles').on('change', gotPic);
});

function gotPic(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      if (event.target.files[i].type.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])
        $('#preview').append('<img src = ' + src + '><br>');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple="" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="morefiles">
<br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: but i want to display multiple image @sideroxylon