# how to show a jpeg in angular from a http request which send back a jpeg file

Tags: angularjs, image, cordova, ionic-framework, jpeg

I’m currently working on a ionic/cordova application developed with angularJS.
I need to include an image provided by a secured API requiring an HTTP authorization in a template and can’t find a way to make it work.
The API returns the jpeg with the appropriate response headers.

Here is the way my app calls the image :

```
 $http(req).
        then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             return data;

  });
```

I tried to insert the « code » of this jpeg in a src/ng-src/data-ng-src with a base64 reencoded string (or not) and even tried to convert it in a Blob in order to use the FileReader(); 
I also made an attempt to sanitize it with `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s(https|file|blob|cdvfile|content):|data:image\//);`

None of these solutions worked !

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: What is the format in which you receive this file?

Comment: Can you provide an exemple of "api" or something similar? I try with some other websites but I only get `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` bla bla bla...

Comment: have you tried with ng-scr="data:image/jpeg;base64" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235246/angularjs-display-base64-image

Comment: I receive the file in JPEG, and yes I tried the "data:..."

Comment: The Api I use is a personnal API developped at my job by someone else, and he prefers to send back a JPEG rather than a base64 file.